# Error al importar modulo desde subcarpeta Python

Tags: python, importación

estoy intentando ejecutar ciertas funciones desde un archivo .py desde una subcarpeta, pero no logro hacerlo funcionar, cuando ejecuto el mismo codigo dentro del archivo "*helpers\screen_search.py*" funciona correctamente, pero al hacerlo desde "*principal.py*" me indica el siguiente error

```
C:\Users\Administrator\PycharmProjects\proyectoKN\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:\Users\Administrator\PycharmProjects\proyectoKN\principal.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\PycharmProjects\proyectoKN\principal.py", line 3, in <module>
    from helpers.screen_search import search_text_image
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\PycharmProjects\proyectoKN\helpers\screen_search.py", line 10, in <module>
    from handlers import get_project_root, window_message, file_exist, istuple, isstring, isint
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'handlers'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Esta es la estructura del proyecto

```
proyectoKN
  ├── helpers
  │    ├── temp_img
  │    │    └── asd.png
  │    ├── __init__.py
  │    ├── handlers.py 
  │    ├── keyboard.py
  │    ├── mouse.py
  │    ├── screen.py
  │    └── screen_search.py
  └── images
  │    └── bar_item
  │         └── location
  └── resources
  └── principal.py
```

Esto es lo que contiene el archivo **principal.py**

```
import time
import pyautogui as pya
from helpers.screen_search import search_text_image
#from helpers import screen_search // da el mismo error

time.sleep(2)
pya.screenshot(imageFilename=r"helpers\temp_img\asd.png", region=(40, 13, 180, 84))
print(search_text_image("helpers/temp_img/asd.png"))
#print(screen_search.search_text_image("helpers/temp_img/asd.png")) // da el mismo error
```

Este es el codigo que contiene el archivo "*helpers/screen_search.py*" (acortado)

```
import pyautogui as pya
import pyscreeze
try:
    from PIL import Image
except ImportError:
    import Image
from PIL import ImageGrab
import pytesseract as pyt
from handlers import get_project_root, window_message, file_exist, istuple, isstring, isint
from mouse import move_to
pyt.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'

#busca una imagen en la pantalla y devuelve las coordenadas en caso de encontrarla
def search_image(path, center=None, tolerance=None):
    ...

def search_text(x, y, xsize, ysize, language='spa'):
    ...

def search_text_image(image_path, language='spa'):
    ...
```

Pienso que puede ser algun problema con las importaciones del archivo "*screen_search.py*", pero cuando ejecuto el mismo codigo dentro del mismo funciona correctamente

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: @FranciscoJavier encontre un archivo llamado "distutils-precedence.pth", si es a ese al que te refieres, debo añadir la ruta como importacion?

esto es lo que me sale en dicho documento.

import os; var = 'SETUPTOOLS_USE_DISTUTILS'; enabled = os.environ.get(var, 'local') == 'local'; enabled and __import__('_distutils_hack').add_shim();

Comment: @FranciscoJavier no funciono, sigue apareciendo el mismo mensaje

Answer (score 0):

Lo solucione importando path desde sys y añadiendo la ruta de la sub-carpeta al path.

El archivo **principal.py** quedo de la siguiente manera

```
import time
import pyautogui as pya
from helpers.handlers import get_project_root
from sys import path
path.append(fr"{get_project_root()}/helpers")
from helpers.screen_search import search_text_image

time.sleep(2)
pya.screenshot(imageFilename=r"helpers\temp_img\asd.png", region=(40, 13, 180, 84))
print(search_text_image(r"helpers\temp_img\asd.png"))
```

la funcion *get_project_root()* contiene lo siguiente

```
from pathlib import Path

def get_project_root() -> Path:
    return Path(__file__).parent.parent
```